# How to Download and Parse a JSON string faster over HTTP in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, io, httpurlconnection

Currently, I'm working on tuneup client/server application communicated via http using `HttpURLConnection`.

Here, the client sends a `java-serializable object` as the request to a server (`HttpServlet` receives this) and it receives a `JSON` string as the response.

Then that `JSON` response is forwarded to a `JSON` parser to process.

Previously, first we downloaded and constructed the complete `JSON` string comming through the `stream` and then we forwarded it to the parser. Then I tuned it up to forward the `stream` it-self to the parser (`Jackson Streaming parser`) and let it to process on the part that it receives without waiting to download the entire `JSON` string.

This gives good results when the download speed is good. But here I'm getting not that much good results in one environment, since it is getting so much time to download and it process very faster. (sometimes 17(s) to download 4-5MB JSON string).

How can tune this up to download and parse the JSON faster than this?

**Client**

```
URL url = new URL(http://myhost.com/Connectors/url2Service);
HttpURLConnection servletConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

servletConnection.setDoInput(true);  
servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
servletConnection.setUseCaches (false);  
servletConnection.setDefaultUseCaches (false);  
servletConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
servletConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/x-java-serialized-object");
servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");
servletConnection.setRequestProperty("user-agent","Mozilla(MSIE)");
servletConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
servletConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
servletConnection.connect();


String encodingHeader = servletConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding");

String contentType = servletConnection.getHeaderField("content-type");

if(contentType.equals("application/json")){

    InputStream inputStream = servletConnection.getInputStream();

    if(encodingHeader != null && encodingHeader.toLowerCase().indexOf("gzip") != -1) {

        gzipis = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);

    } else {

        iSR = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        br = new BufferedReader(iSR);

    }

    ResposeObject resposeObject = new JsonString2ResposeObject().parse(gzipis); // previously we passed complete String here
}
```

**Server**

```
public class url2Service extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
            RequestObject requestObject = (RequestObject) ois.readObject();

            response.setContentType("application/json");

            String jsonResponseString = new ServerApplication().doMoreWithRequest(requestObject);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = null;

            if (null != aEncoding && aEncoding.toLowerCase().indexOf("gzip") != -1) {
                gzipos = new GZIPOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                wr = new OutputStreamWriter(gzipos);                    
                response.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");                 
            } else {
                wr = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
            }

            wr.write(jsonString);
            wr.flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really need to transfer 5MB of text in a single response? Maybe you can break it into chunks and serve them partially.

Comment: You're already gzipping data, streaming it, and passing the inputStream to the parser. It's unclear what you're asking here. You cannot really parse data before it's downloaded, so if your download takes `17s`, the overall parsing will take `17s + parsing time`.

Comment: Appology if it is unclear.. I measure 17s not within the code. I mean if I let the JSON downloaded completely it will take 17s. That is true that the overall parsing will take 17s + parsing time. And I know that I cannot really parse data before it's downloaded. But I can start parsing the JSON string with the part of the JSON String that is downloaded without waiting for all the content right?

Comment: @Stefan : Yes but I can find a repeated parts and send. Thank u Stefan for the IDEA

Comment: @Stefan : I did this. But no luck. You mean to do  wr.write(jsonStringChunk); wr.flush(); multiple times for small chunks of JSON response in server side right? In the client side, I didn't do any changes.  But It didn't give me an improvement. Now I'm trying to compress/decompress it and see.